# Rotation around non-zero point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations

$$\begin{cases}x' = x \cos(\varphi) - y \sin(\varphi) \\ y' = x \sin(\varphi) + y \cos(\varphi)\end{cases}$$

This a the formula for rotating $(x, y)$ by $\varphi$. It works well when I want to rotate rectangle's vertices which is centered in $(0, 0)$ but what if  center is not zero and It's something like $(5, 10)$ ?

Comment: transfer it to origin. rotate. then transfer it back to its original place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then the formula will just change to accomodate the new origin.

$$x' = 5+(x-5) \cos(\varphi) - (y-10) \sin(\varphi) \\ y' = 10+(x-5) \sin(\varphi) + (y-10) \cos(\varphi)$$

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks but It only works on $x'$,  When I want to rotate $(40.89, 40.26)$ around $(40.39, 41.01)$, The formula you gave gives $x' = 41.80921000000001$ which I didn't test it yet but seems reasonable however $y' = 98.37548999999999$ which is too far from being true

Comment: @omidh It was a mistake and I am sorry for it. Actually it should have gone as follows. It also matches with the formula given by msm.

Answer (score 1):

1. Transfer the points to the origin
   $$\begin{bmatrix}
   x'
   \\
   y' 
   \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
   x-5
   \\ 
   y-10
   \end{bmatrix}$$
2. Rotate

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x''
\\
y''
\end{bmatrix}=R\begin{bmatrix}
x'
\\ 
y'
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $$R=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\phi)& -\sin(\phi)
\\ 
\sin(\phi)&\cos(\phi)
\end{bmatrix}$$

3. Transfer back to the original place
   $$\begin{bmatrix}
   x'''
   \\
   y''' 
   \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
   x''+5
   \\ 
   y''+10
   \end{bmatrix}$$

So the overall transform becomes:
 $$\begin{bmatrix}
x'''
\\
y''' 
\end{bmatrix}=
R\begin{bmatrix}
x-5
\\ 
y-10
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
5
\\ 
10
\end{bmatrix}$$